# PCB etching from transparency

Tags: pcb, trace

I wonder if someone could help me. A few days ago, my brother gave me all of his electronics, seeing that he doesn't need it anymore. I'm keen to learn electronics in depth and have basic knowledge such as resistor formulations, etc.

Scratching around in the stuff, I found something that looks like a very small xray of a PCB. After explaining to me what it was, he encouraged me to build it. I tried googling around about how to make it, but my search came back unsuccessful. Can't ask my brother how to do it, because he's out of the country on work.

So here's the question: How do I make the rails on the PCB? Everyone mentions using acid - what do I use and where would I typically find it?

Comment: Look up PCB etching.

Comment: Cool! Will do so!

Comment: When you're searching the "x-ray" is normally called a transparency film which should give you better results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Stripboard

If you are starting out, I'd suggest using [stripboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stripboard) to start with.

### Etching PCBs

The "X-ray" is (probably) a Printed Circuit Board (PCB) design that shows where copper conductive tracks should be retained on a *copper clad board* which is to *etched* using an etchant such as Ferric Chloride.

In order to prevent the tracks being etched, a etch resist coating is applied to the copper which is destroyed by the combination of ultra-violet light and an alkali developer. Shining UV on the coated board through the transparency for a few minutes then developing it will leave the coating on the dark areas of the transparency but not on the exposed areas. You can then etch it.

There are other etchants and various ways of producing PCBs at home. Ferric Chloride is moderately nasty stuff - it will stain anything it comes into contact with and must not be flushed down drains - so disposing of used etchant can be problematic.

[Here](http://quinndunki.com/blondihacks/?p=351) is a reasonably detailed description that includes a section on an alternative etchant that may be less problematic.

---

Addendum (I'm trying to find some old articles I recall reading)

### Etchants

- Ferric Chloride ("traditional" but nasty).
- [Ammonium Persulphate](http://sfprime.net/pcb-etching/#etching) (see comments below)
- [Vinegar + hydrogen peroxide](http://quinndunki.com/blondihacks/?p=835)
- [white vinegar, hydrogen peroxide, and salt](http://www.stephenhobley.com/blog/2011/03/02/still-messing-with-forces-i-dont-understand-the-formula/)
- [hydrochloric acid and hydrogen peroxide](http://www.instructables.com/id/Stop-using-Ferric-Chloride-etchant!--A-better-etc/)

Theres a nice article on the chemistry republished at [Adafruit](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2009/01/25/the-chemistry-of-home-etched-pcbs/)

> it seems far better to me to
>   avoid ferric chloride altogether and simply use acidified copper chloride,
>   or better yet, simply start with an alternative oxidant such as hydrogen
>   peroxide, and let copper accumulate in solution and eventually take over.
>   An acidic copper chloride etchant can be reused indefinitely, provided that
>   HCl is added periodically to provide the protons for the reoxidation
>   reaction. Indeed, such an etchant solution actually improves with age!

### Non-chemical methods

- CNC machining.
- [Electrolosis](http://www.diystompboxes.com/smfforum/index.php?topic=63011.0))
- Conductive ink (hardly worth including?)

Comment: I haven't made my own PCBs for years, but I think nowadays Ammonium Persulphate is more common. Remember as a kid spilling Ferric Chloride all over the kitchen floor and wasn't too popular.

Comment: @PeterJ I just use Peridrol+sparse Hydrochloric acid, etching takes just a minute but should be used in open space (or with ventilation) and is highly caustic so it's not for novices. The mixture can also be used to make [Acid Cupric Chloride](http://members.optusnet.com.au/~eseychell/PCB/etching_CuCl/) that can be regenerated with air and be used multiple times. [Making cupric chloride etchant](http://jimlaurwilliams.org/wordpress/?p=2913)